# Mongoose: Embed a model as array of another model

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have menu items that have certain roles that make links to them restrictive.

**1. RoleModel.js**

```
     const MenuRoleSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
          name: { type: String, unique: true}, { _id: true });

     exports.MenuRoleModel = mongoose.model('MenuRoleModel', MenuRoleSchema, 'menu_role');
```

**2. MenuItemModel.js**

```
    const MenuItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      ......
      roles: [ { type: MenuRoleModel } ] 
    });
```

**3. MenuItemSeed.js**

```
   const data = [
          {
            .....
            "roles": [{"name": "RoleA"}],
          },
          {
            ....
            "roles": [{"name": "RoleA"}, {"name": "RoleB"}],
          }

        ]
```

My MenuItemModel is not populating in the database, and naturally no errors are provided.

How would I structure my schema so the seed data as currently laid out for roles works?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick for me:

**1. RoleModel.js**

```
    (1)export const MenuRoleSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
      name: { type: String, unique: true}, { _id: true });

    exports.MenuRoleModel = mongoose.model('MenuRoleModel', MenuRoleSchema, 'menu_role');
```

**2. MenuItemModel.js**

```
     (2)import {MenuRoleSchema} from './RoleModel';

        const MenuItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        ......
        roles: [ { type: MenuRoleSchema } ] (3)
     });
```